# Android app taking too much memory on startup

Tags: java, android

I'm building an applicaton, till now I have three interfaces ( Login, Sign up, Welcome page).
In the login page, I have an image (png, 7.57 KB), underneath it there is two edittexts and two buttons. The activity background is an image (png, 61 KB).
In the sign up, I only have edittexts and a buttons, no images no icons.
In the welcome page, I have a gridview (3 columns 3 rows ), each grid item have an icon (png, maximum 4KB).

I'm setting the sizes of everything in the app inside the java code.I'm getting the width and height using this method:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
```

And setting the size using the following:

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width*40/100,width*40/100));
```

When I checked the "active applications" section in my device, I found that the application is consuming 85 MB from memory which is too much. I searched for the reason, there was advices about using png instead of jpg but it didn't make the difference.

If you have any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have other resources loaded outside images? Are you using a DB or other Datasources which could possibly consume RAM? The developer site also gives best practices for a small memory footprint.

Comment: No till now I don't have any other datasource, everything is in drawable folder

Comment: On most devices and without largeHeap enabled you will get a OOM far before reaching that 85mb, please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: I guess we won't be able to tell. You'll have to inspect the App for what consumes those Megabytes with a debugger / analysation tool.

Comment: [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) has some tipps. You might find some interesting stuff when scrolling down to "Viewing Heap updates".